# How to toggle company-mode with $ prefix?

Tags: company-mode

When I write JavaScript code, company does not toggle when prefix is `$`, how to fix it?

```
(setq company-idle-delay 0)
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 0)
(setq company-auto-complete t)
(setq company-require-match nil)
```

Comment: Which company backand are you using? ac-js2, company-tern or jquery-doc.el?

Comment: it's up to the backend to determine when a prefix is valid. So as @Jules said, knowing what backend you are using makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need `company-dabbrev-code` ; my config :

```
(use-package company
  :init
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1
        company-selection-wrap-around t
        company-dabbrev-code-ignore-case t
        company-dabbrev-downcase nil
        company-dabbrev-ignore-case t
        company-backends
        '((company-dabbrev-code)
          (company-yasnippet
           company-capf           ; completion-at-point-functions
           company-files          ; files & directory
           company-keywords)))
  ;; (setq company-dabbrev-downcase nil)
  (eval-after-load 'company
    '(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-dabbrev-code company-yasnippet company-abbrev company-dabbrev company-capf))))
```